# Style email form fields

Tags: html, css, form-fields

I have a contact form that was pieced together. The form works exactly the way I need it after much struggling, but doesn't look right.
The first two fields for the phone number have a different appearance then then others.
How can I get the first two to look like the other 3?

*yes im sure there is lots of errors in this code as im learning, but currently it is working. Ill go back after reading/learning more to correct issue(hopefully).
How can I make first two look the same?
Thanks

```
    <div style="background-color: #ff69b4;"margin: -5px 12px 0px 10px"><div style="margin-left:10px; margin-right: 10px;">
<center><br><br><div id="contentinner">
<div class="content">

<div class="form">
<form id="form1" method="post" action="form-process.php" onsubmit="return checkSelection('form1');">

<input type="hidden" name="thank_you_url" value="./thank you" />
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="./contact-us.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Contact from Website" />
<div style="width:50%">
<!-- Start Form Fields -->

phone number<br>
<input name="phone" required="required" type="phone" id="phone" />
<br>confirm phone
<br>
<input name="phone_confirm" required="required" type="phone" id="phone_confirm" oninput="check(this)"  />
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function check(input) {
if (input.value != document.getElementById('phone').value) {
input.setCustomValidity('Phone Number Must be Matching.');
} else {
// input is valid -- reset the error message
input.setCustomValidity('');
}
}
</script>


<br>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
name<input type="text" name="name" required>

email<input type="email" name="email" required>




<label>more information<?php form_error('Comments');?></label>
<textarea name="Comments" cols="" rows="" class="textarea" required></textarea>









<!-- End Form Fields -->

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />   
</div>

</div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkSelection(whichform) {
if(document.forms[whichform].required.value) {
    var required = document.forms[whichform].required.value.split(','), errors = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        if(document.forms[whichform][required[i]].value == "") {
            errors = true;
        }
    }
    if (errors) {
        alert ('Whoops! You must fill in all required fields before you can continue.');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true; 
    }
}
}

//-->
</script>

</form>
</div></div>
</center>
```

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #ff69b4;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
}
.outer {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:grey;
    height:350px;
}
input
{
    width:150px;
    height:20px;

}
textarea
{
width:150px;    
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QFqY/20/)

[image]

Dont ever use the <[Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) > tag..!

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may
>   still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it
>   in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any
>   time.

To give effects to phone text box add class to the input text box and add css to the class

**HtMl**

```
 <input class="phones" name="phone" required="required"
        type="phone" id="phone" />
 <br>
  confirm phone
  <br>
  <input class="phones" name="phone_confirm" required="required"
          type="phone" id="phone_confirm" oninput="check(this)" />
```

**Css**

```
.phones
{
    background-color:#003366;
    color:white;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3QFqY/21/)

[image]

## [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QFqY/25/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I apply this to the other 3 fields(name,email,comment) as the theme is styling them to look different then the phone ones

Comment: you need all the text box to be same??

Comment: Yes I need them all the same. Thanks for the help. I was originally tring to get the first two to be like the last three as they re-sized by when the screen size got smaller. But just having them all match is better than how I had it. I cant figure though how to get the last 3 now the same as other 2 you did.

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you. When I add it all to thwe page it through everything off and didnt show all the fields for some reason. So I added just the input class phones to the phone filds and it worked that way but when I added it to the others it didnt. Ill go and retry it all.

Comment: and let me know after checking..!! :)

Comment: I had to use parts of it all and its all there except the email. Example I used  <input class="phones" name="name" required="required" type="input" id="name" />  for the name field in the edited form, did the similar with message/comment and they are good but if I change type to email for the email filed the styling goes away. If I use this= <input class="phones" name="email" required="required" type="email" id="email" /> it goes back to having no style, validates the email as should. SO im just stuck at getting the email field styled.....sorry for delay and thank you

Comment: yes it works(validates email) using whats on fiddle except it doesnt have the new styling. If I change input type from "email" to "input" the styling is there but doesn't validate it as its no longer email type. Its only this email field now making an issue.

Comment: what issue you are facing??

Comment: When I use this on my site=<input class="phones" name="email" required="required" type="email" id="email" /> the styling isnt applying

Comment: i guess there may be style code written for #email check for it..!!

Comment: ok. Just looked, yes there is. If I change it it would change the style on my other form yes? Is there a way to create one named something else maybe just for this form and the email field?

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to remove the quote between your background color and margin in the uppermost style.

I think its because you've placed the second form in the div with a 50% width. Its being centered because it has `<center>` as a parent element. The center is deprecated in HTML5. This should be done up in CSS. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) for details.

For your code, try using either Brackets or Sublime Text. I use Brackets for work.

Also, you don't need to declare `type="text/javascript"` anymore. You can remove that for cleaner code.

For learning how to do front-end, this is a great try. When you feel you're beginning to understand, check out Twitter Bootstrap.

Here's my go at cleaning up your code. Notice the one warning it has given you in the JavaScript. http://jsbin.com/hijec/1/edit

Comment: The first form is being (a) centered and (b) has a 100% width. The second form is (a) centered and (b) has a 50% width. The input and the labels have been squished down to the point where the input had to go onto a new line.

Comment: it looks right on the page/link you sent but when putting it one my site the last three fields are different. Its like the last three use the whatever styling thats in the theme and the first 2 dont. If that makes sense

Comment: upvotes for mentioning about the deprication of <center>, i have seen many using the tag, i personally suggest everyone not to use the tag, and here in answers no one has said about the deprication, you have educated the fellow author.. kudos..!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the line breaks... just remove them! http://jsfiddle.net/L92dp/1/

```
confirm phone
<br> <!-- remove this -->
```

You should have a look at a CSS framework like bootstrap or foundation, it will help you write beautiful forms easily.

Comment: Not the line breaks, the fact the the field looks totally different. Has a different size and also a totally different appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your both input field look alike same .it depends on what style using from imported Css file.First Check in your Css file there should be same type of style for fields
    if style written on the basis for ID then

```
 id="phone" & id="phone_confirm" have same style
or 
 on the basis of name both phone and phone_confirm should be same.
```

Comment: yes the last three use the style from the theme as they look like the other forms on the site. So how can I make the first two use the same style?

Comment: you should use same style of email and name from the CSS file
and for this you can give style to phone and phone_confirm by using
',' and put these form fields name or id with them.

suppose
#email {
/////
}

now use 
#email,#phone,#phone_confirm{
/////////
}

Comment: thanks Balram, this sounds like what I need to do, but just have to figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content  { /*color: #fff;*/ }
```

*and / or*

```
.form  { /*color: #fff;*/ }
```

*and / or*

```
#form1  { /*color: #fff;*/ }
```

*and / or*

```
input { /*color: #fff;*/ }
```

*and cool link*

http://css-tricks.com/styling-texty-inputs-only/

It could also be easier to read if you removed your inline and unnecessary nested divs etc:

```
<div style="background-color: #ff69b4;"margin: -5px 12px 0px 10px"><div style="margin-left:10px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

to

```
.pickaclassname { 
     background-color: #ff69b4;
     margin: -5px 12px 0px 10px;
     margin-left:10px; 
     margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Try using comments to help organize your code to compare and contrast with the forms.

```
<!-- my awesome form 1 -->

(all the form code)

<!-- // end form 1 -->

<!-- my awesome form 2 -->

(all the form code)

<!-- // end form 2 -->
```